# How to avoid the rectangle shape when cropping?

Tags: android

I am using the following code to perform cropping:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

But I can do cropping only in rectangular shapes.

There is an App called "Document Scanner trial version" (free app) that is able to perform cropping of different shapes.

Is there any option to change this rectangle shape?

Comment: There is no `CROP` `Intent` in Android: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: so,can I find the solution from the github links provided by you

Comment: You should crop the image before you send it with the intent.

Comment: The links in my blog post are for some image cropping libraries for Android. There may be others. You are welcome to write your own (and you will probably need to in order to "perform cropping of different shapes", if one of those libraries does not already offer it). My point is that, even if you did not need to "perform cropping of different shapes", using `com.android.camera.action.CROP` is unreliable.

Comment: can you please suggest for the solution?